# How to print field type image in views-view-fields--xyz--block.tpl.php

Tags: views, media

How to print field type image in this page?

I'm using this code:

```
print $fields['field_xyz']->content;"
```

Is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use [field_view_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7).

E.g.

```
$node = node_load($node_id);
print drupal_render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_your_field_name'));
```

Or if you don't want the label with the field then:

```
print drupal_render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_your_field_name', array('label' => 'hidden')))
```